# Approximation of binomial distribution - Poisson vs Normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

Suppose we have a random variable $X \sim \text{Bin}(n, p)$ and we want to approximate $\mathbb{P}\left[X = k\right]$.

In my statistics course we learned two ways to do this:

- By using the fact that $X \approx \text{Poi}(\lambda = n\cdot p)$
- By using the [DeMoivre-Laplace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem), thus approximating $X$ by the use of the normal distribution

I understand how to apply both of them, but in the context of an exam I am unsure which one to choose for a given problem, if there is no requirement stated.

What are the requirements, disadvantages, etc.. for the two choices?

Comment: I believe that you can only really use the poisson distribution for this if $n$ is very large and $p$ is very low. I do not know if this is also required for your second option.

Comment: If $n$ is large but $np$ remains away from both $0$ and $\infty$, then $\operatorname{Bin}(n, p) \approx \operatorname{Poisson}(np)$. On the other hand, if $n$ is large but $p \in (0, 1)$ is fixed, then $\operatorname{Bin}(n,p) \approx \mathcal{N}(np, np(1-p))$. They describe quite different situations.

Comment: @SangchulLee The Poisson approximation works fine when $np\to 0,n \to \infty$. It is just that both distributions are concentrated near 0 in this case.

Comment: @Ian, I agree :) I was too cautious about excluding degenerate case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both describes two different limiting distribution of binomial distribution.

1. *Poisson approximation.* If $n$ is large but $np$ is not large, then $\operatorname{Bin}(n, p) \approx \operatorname{Poisson}(np)$. More precisely, if $X_n \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n, p_n)$ and $n p_n \to \lambda \in [0, \infty)$ as $n\to\infty$, then

   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbf{P}(X_n = k) = \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda} \qquad \text{for all} \quad k = 0, 1, 2, \cdots.$$
2. *Normal approximation.* If $n$ is large and $p \in (0, 1)$ is fixed, then $\operatorname{Bin}(n, p) \approx \mathcal{N}(np, np(1-p))$. More precisely, if $X_n \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n, p)$, then

   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbf{P}\left( \frac{X_n - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \leq z \right) = \int_{-\infty}^{z} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2} \, \mathrm{d}x \qquad \text{for all} \quad z \in \mathbb{R}.$$

As we can check from the precise statements, these approximations primarily cover the limiting cases. So they do not necessarily draws a solid line between two approximations. Perhaps it is better to see directly how both methods perform well for different values of parameters. The followings are plots for these 3 distributions for $n = 1000$ and $p$ varied.

[image: Comparison]

As we see, if $p$ is small, then Poisson approximation is much better (so that even plot markers for those two distributions are rarely distinguishable), while Normal approximation is better for large $p$. Also there are some grey area where both approximates the binomial distribution moderately well.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very nice answer. So, given a question in an exam, I should do my choice depending on $p$? For example, in an example where multiple coin tosses were observed I would choose the normal approximation, since $p=0.5$ is rather large, right?

Comment: @Katharina, That is right. :)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: What I don't like about your answer: 1) "Poisson when $n$ is large and $np$ is not large" ? What do you mean by "large" and "not large" exactly? 2) "Normal when $p$ is fixed" ? The question is: Given $n$ and $p$, what is a better approximation, Poisson or normal? Of course $p$ is fixed!